# Erroneous tree type in java

Tags: java, crawler4j

I am trying to run the following code for `BasicCrawlController` in java but I get some error:

```
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.examples.basic;

import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.fetcher.PageFetcher;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.robotstxt.RobotstxtConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.robotstxt.RobotstxtServer;

/**
 * @author Yasser Ganjisaffar <lastname at gmail dot com>
 */
public class MyWebCrawler {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                if (args.length != 2) {
                        System.out.println("Needed parameters: ");
                        System.out.println("\t rootFolder (it will contain intermediate crawl data)");
                        System.out.println("\t numberOfCralwers (number of concurrent threads)");
                        return;
                }

                /*
                 * crawlStorageFolder is a folder where intermediate crawl data is
                 * stored.
                 */
                String crawlStorageFolder = args[0];

                /*
                 * numberOfCrawlers shows the number of concurrent threads that should
                 * be initiated for crawling.
                 */
                int numberOfCrawlers = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

                CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();

                config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);

                /*
                 * Be polite: Make sure that we don't send more than 1 request per
                 * second (1000 milliseconds between requests).
                 */
                config.setPolitenessDelay(1000);

                /*
                 * You can set the maximum crawl depth here. The default value is -1 for
                 * unlimited depth
                 */
                config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(2);

                /*
                 * You can set the maximum number of pages to crawl. The default value
                 * is -1 for unlimited number of pages
                 */
                config.setMaxPagesToFetch(1000);

                /*
                 * Do you need to set a proxy? If so, you can use:
                 * config.setProxyHost("proxyserver.example.com");
                 * config.setProxyPort(8080);
                 *
                 * If your proxy also needs authentication:
                 * config.setProxyUsername(username); config.getProxyPassword(password);
                 */

                /*
                 * This config parameter can be used to set your crawl to be resumable
                 * (meaning that you can resume the crawl from a previously
                 * interrupted/crashed crawl). Note: if you enable resuming feature and
                 * want to start a fresh crawl, you need to delete the contents of
                 * rootFolder manually.
                 */
                config.setResumableCrawling(false);

                /*
                 * Instantiate the controller for this crawl.
                 */
                PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
                RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
                RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
                CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

                /*
                 * For each crawl, you need to add some seed urls. These are the first
                 * URLs that are fetched and then the crawler starts following links
                 * which are found in these pages
                 */

                controller.addSeed("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");
                controller.addSeed("http://www.ics.uci.edu/~lopes/");
                controller.addSeed("http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/");

                /*
                 * Start the crawl. This is a blocking operation, meaning that your code
                 * will reach the line after this only when crawling is finished.
                 */
                controller.start(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
        }
}
```

the error is:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at mywebcrawler.MyWebCrawler.main(MyWebCrawler.java:107)
```

what is the problem with the code? it is completely copied from thw web site of crawler4j!

Comment: It's a log4j setup problem.  The answer is unlikely to be in the code that's posted.

Comment: @Michael line 107 is this: controller.start(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the log4j properties file.

Comment: I don't think so. I have pasted the contents of log4j.properties:

Comment: log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] %m%n

Comment: On the other hand, the message says that the error is: Erroneous tree type !!!! about which I have no idea!

Answer (score 0):

What is `BasicCrawler`, is that your own class? How did you define it, is it a generic class? Haven't you forgot specifying the generic type?

Comment: BasicCrawler is also a class that I got from the homepage of Crawler4j. In the following answer you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

BasicCrawler is a class that I copied from crawler4j documentation:

```
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.parser.HtmlParseData;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class BasicCrawler extends WebCrawler {
    private final static Pattern FILTERS = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g" + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4"
                    + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf" + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

    /**
     * You should implement this function to specify whether the given url
     * should be crawled or not (based on your crawling logic).
     */
    @Override
    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
            String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
            return !FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() && href.startsWith("http://www.aut.ac.ir/");
    }

    /**
     * This function is called when a page is fetched and ready to be processed
     * by your program.
     */
    @Override
    public void visit(Page page) {
            int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
            String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
            String domain = page.getWebURL().getDomain();
            String path = page.getWebURL().getPath();
            String subDomain = page.getWebURL().getSubDomain();
            String parentUrl = page.getWebURL().getParentUrl();

            System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            System.out.println("Domain: '" + domain + "'");
            System.out.println("Sub-domain: '" + subDomain + "'");
            System.out.println("Path: '" + path + "'");
            System.out.println("Parent page: " + parentUrl);

            if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
                    HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
                    String text = htmlParseData.getText();
                    String html = htmlParseData.getHtml();
                    List<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();

                    System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
                    System.out.println("Html length: " + html.length());
                    System.out.println("Number of outgoing links: " + links.size());
            }

            System.out.println("=============");
    }
}
```